# Como pasar value de input serializado a controlador por metodo get? Laravel PHP

Tags: php, laravel

estoy trabajando en una tienda que cuenta con un carrito de compras.. La cuestion es que le agregue a los productos sus respectivos talles y colores... Los talles y colores son almacenados en la base de datos y están serializados... Para mostrar el color y el talle los des-serializo y los pongo en un bucle for para recorrerlos y mostralos en un input... estos input se crean de forma dinamica con el for obviamente. Por lo que no le puedo asignar un name estatico... creo que deberia serializarlo de vuelta para enviarlo al controlador... en fin.. Lo que quiero hacer es poder enviar el value de mi input de talles y colores a mi funcion add de mi carrito de compras que esta en mi controlador para poder guardarla en una variable de sesion asi como lo hago con la cantidad... alguna ayuda de como puedo hacer esto?

Mi plantilla

```
<div class="product_size">
            <div class="product_size_title">Seleccione talle</div>
            <ul class="d-flex flex-row align-items-start justify-content-start">
              @for($i=0; $i < $cantidad; $i++)
              <li>
                <input type="radio" value="{{$talle[$i]}}" onclick="selectTalle(this)" id="radio_{{$i}}" name="talle[]" class="regular_radio">
                <label for="radio_{{$i}}">{{$talle[$i]}}</label>
              </li>
              @endfor
            </ul>
            <div class="product_size_title">Seleccione color</div>
            <ul class="d-flex flex-row align-items-start justify-content-start">
              @for($i=0; $i < $cont; $i++)
              <li>
                <input onclick="selectColor(this)" value="{{$color['color'. $i]}}" type="radio" id="color_{{$i}}" name="pro_color[]" class="regular_radio2" checked>
                <label for="color_{{$i}}" style="background-color: {{$color['color'. $i]}};"></label>
              </li>
              @endfor
            </ul>
            <a href="javascript: void(0);"onclick="window.open('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u={{$url}}&display=popup&ref=plugin&src=like&kid_directed_site=0&app_id=113869198637480','popup', 'toolbar=0, status=0, width=650, height=450');">
            Compartir en facebook</a>
          </div>

<div onclick="window.location.href='{{ url('/cart', $producto->pro_id) }}'" class="product_button product_cart text-center d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center">
```

mi controlador

```
public function add(Producto $product){
    $cart = \Session::get('cart');
    $product->quantity = 1; //la cantidad del producto es 1 por default
    $cart[$product->pro_id] = $product;
    \Session::put('cart', $cart);
    return redirect()->route('cart-show');

}
```

mi idea es poder recibir el color y talle y grabarlos en una variable asi como hago con la cantidad de los productos...

La captura del value del input puedo hacerlas con js

```
function selectTalle(e) {
  var id_elemento = $(e).val();
  console.log(id_elemento);
}



function selectColor(e) {
  var id_elemento = $(e).val();
  console.log(id_elemento);
}
```

asi cuando le da click al input ya obtengo el valor del input que quiero... ahora.. como hago para enviar estos datos al controlador es lo que me gustaria saber...

Comment: ¿Solo necesitas enviar los datos al controlador? ¿Como quieres enviarlos, AJAX o formulario? ¿En que momento han de guardarse?

Comment: En realidad no tengo ningun formulario ni una peticion ajax... lo que hago es simplemente enviar el id del producto por get y listo...

Comment: Entonces, envias un get con todo y el problema es procesar los parametros que no son id?

Comment: El problema es como hago para enviar solamente el value del input talle y color seleccionado... Con javascript puedo capturar el value  pero eso como lo paso a una variable php y enviarlo por get... voy a actualizar mi pregunta pregunta para agregar el js

Comment: Ya veo, el boton que se encarga de hacer el GET es el div ese con evento de click no?

Comment: si amigo........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La manera más sencilla, seria creando un formulario:

```
<div class="product_size">
        <form action="{{ url('/cart', $producto->pro_id) }} method="GET">
            <div class="product_size_title">Seleccione talle</div>
            <ul class="d-flex flex-row align-items-start justify-content-start">
              @for($i=0; $i < $cantidad; $i++)
              <li>
                <input type="radio" value="{{$talle[$i]}}" onclick="selectTalle(this)" id="radio_{{$i}}" name="talle[]" class="regular_radio">
                <label for="radio_{{$i}}">{{$talle[$i]}}</label>
              </li>
              @endfor
            </ul>
            <div class="product_size_title">Seleccione color</div>
            <ul class="d-flex flex-row align-items-start justify-content-start">
              @for($i=0; $i < $cont; $i++)
              <li>
                <input onclick="selectColor(this)" value="{{$color['color'. $i]}}" type="radio" id="color_{{$i}}" name="pro_color[]" class="regular_radio2" checked>
                <label for="color_{{$i}}" style="background-color: {{$color['color'. $i]}};"></label>
              </li>
              @endfor
            </ul>
            <a href="javascript: void(0);"onclick="window.open('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u={{$url}}&display=popup&ref=plugin&src=like&kid_directed_site=0&app_id=113869198637480','popup', 'toolbar=0, status=0, width=650, height=450');">
            Compartir en facebook</a>
          </div>
          <button class="product_button product_cart text-center d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center">Enviar</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Si por lo que sea, quieres que sea por javascript como tenias, esto seria un metodo:

```
<div onclick="onClick" class="product_button product_cart text-center d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center"></div>

<script>
    function onClick () {
        const colores = document.querySelectorAll('[id^=color_]');
        const talles = document.querySelectorAll('[id^=radio_]');
        let url = "{{ url('/cart', $producto->pro_id) }}" + "?";

        talles.forEach(el => {
            if (el.checked) {
                url += "talle[]=" + el.value + "&";
            }
        });

        colores.forEach(el => {
            if (el.checked) {
                url += "pro_color[]=" + el.value + "&";
            }
        });

        window.location.href = url;
    }
</script>
```

Controlador: añadimos $request, el cual estara disponible si el controlador esta configurado como lo configura Laravel por defecto, este trae un monton de información, entre ello, los parametros.

```
public function add(Request $request, Producto $product){

    $color = $request->pro_color;
    $talle = $request->talle;

    $cart = \Session::get('cart');
    $product->quantity = 1; //la cantidad del producto es 1 por default
    $cart[$product->pro_id] = $product;
    \Session::put('cart', $cart);
    return redirect()->route('cart-show');

}
```

Comment: Me atrae mas la idea de hacerlo con un formulario... en ese caso... como hago para enviar solamente el input talle y color que mi usuario selecciono?

Comment: Gracias.. utilce tu codigo javascript.. gracias capo!

Comment: En el caso del formulario, solo envia los radios que han sido seleccionados, lo mismo con los select, etc.

Comment: Gracias... ahora tengo otro problema... El # que antecede al código del color en el request no me funciona... pero en la uri envía bien... se que es para otro tema ya esta consulta pero si deseas ayudarme te dejo la url https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/245651/no-puedo-pasar-por-url-con-javascript-y-laravel