# No puedo pasar # por url con javascript y laravel

Tags: php, javascript, laravel

Hola estoy tratando de pasar esta uri por metodo get a mi controlador... `http://127.0.0.1:8000/cart/22?talle=S&pro_color=#f00ef6&` cosa que hace perfectamente.. pero en mi controlador con mi request no me funciona.. me trae de esta forma `#requestUri: "/cart/22?talle=S&pro_color="` cuando le borre el # y lo deje asi `http://127.0.0.1:8000/cart/22?talle=S&pro_color=f00ef6&` funciona... alguien puede decirme por que pasa esto?

El codigo js

```
function agregarALCarrito() {
        const colores = document.querySelectorAll('[id^=color_]');
        const talles = document.querySelectorAll('[id^=radio_]');
        let url = "{{ url('/cart', $producto->pro_id) }}" + "?";

        talles.forEach(el => {
            if (el.checked) {
                url += "talle=" + el.value + "&";
            }
        });

        colores.forEach(el => {
            if (el.checked) {
                url += "pro_color=" + el.value + "&";
            }
        });
        console.log(url);
        window.location.href = url;
```

Alguna Ayuda..?

Comment: Creo que es por que en la **url** si existe el signo `#` entiende el navegador que va para algún lado del sitio

Comment: Hay algún modo de hacer que funcione de igual forma?

Comment: Tendrías que escapar la `url` mira lo que dice [acá](https://support.google.com/richmedia/answer/190941?hl=es) espero te sirva

Comment: Usa el encoding del símbolo: %23

Comment: Como uso el encoding Juan?

Comment: y si solo mandas el codigo del color sin el **#** y donde lo necesitas utilizar le concatenas el **#**?

Comment: otra posible "solución" (lo ha escrito Daniel antes que yo jaja) sería NO pasarle el símbolo # y cuando recojas el valor en la otra página, añadirle el símbolo # a mano. No es lo más bonito, pero...

Comment: Y es eso lo que no queria hacer Daniel Mauricio, solo queria saber si hay alguna forma mas practica de solucionar esto

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Utiliza la función `encodeURIComponent()` si vas a utilizar caracteres especiales.

```
window.location.href = encodeURIComponent(url);
```

Para evitar problemas al intentar codificar la url base, prueba de la siguiente manera:

```
function agregarALCarrito() {
    const colores = document.querySelectorAll('[id^=color_]');
    const talles = document.querySelectorAll('[id^=radio_]');
    const urlBase = "{{ url('/cart', $producto->pro_id) }}" + "?";

    let uri = "";

    talles.forEach(el => {
        if (el.checked) {
            uri += "talle=" + el.value + "&";
        }
    });

    colores.forEach(el => {
        if (el.checked) {
            uri += "pro_color=" + el.value + "&";
        }
    });

    window.location.href = urlBase + encodeURIComponent(uri);
}
```

Comment: Esto no me funciona... me dice que la pagina que busco no existe..

Comment: Ahora te edito la respuesta entonces para evitar fallos en la URL base

Comment: Gracias Francisco.. me funciona bien!

Comment: Buen dato gracias

Answer (score 2):

solo debes agregar:

1. `encodeURIComponent()` en javascript.
2. `urldecode()` en laravel.

esto remplazara el `#` por `%23`

**ejemplos:**

```
function agregarALCarrito() {
        const colores = document.querySelectorAll('[id^=color_]');
        const talles = document.querySelectorAll('[id^=radio_]');
        let url = "{{ url('/cart', $producto->pro_id) }}" + "?";

        talles.forEach(el => {
            if (el.checked) {
                url += "talle=" + el.value + "&";
            }
        });

        colores.forEach(el => {
            if (el.checked) {
                url += "pro_color=" + encodeURIComponent(el.value) + "&";
            }
        });
        console.log(url);
        window.location.href = url;
```

**y en laravel:**

```
$pro_color = urldecode($request->get('pro_color'));
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta... esto tambien me funciona